# Buttons in Newt

Tags: c, linux, terminal, widget, window

I need a simple terminal-based window/widget library with a C or C++ interface in Linux. I found newt, which seems good enough for my needs, but I just have one issue which I cannot get around and google hasn't been very helpful:
How do I determine which button was pressed? Below is a simple button example with 2 buttons - "Ok" and "Cancel". How do I determine which was pressed?

```
#include <newt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
    newtComponent form, b1, b2;
    newtInit();
    newtCls();

    newtOpenWindow(10, 5, 40, 6, "Button Sample");

    b1 = newtButton(10, 1, "Ok");
    b2 = newtCompactButton(22, 2, "Cancel");
    form = newtForm(NULL, NULL, 0);
    newtFormAddComponents(form, b1, b2, NULL);

    newtRunForm(form);

    newtFormDestroy(form);
    newtFinished();
}
```

UPDATE:
After receiving feedback I haved tried to add a callback function as per my understanding:

```
#include <newt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void b1Callback(newComponent co, void * data)
{
    *((int*)data) = 4;
}

void main(void) {
    void* data;
    *((int*)data) = 0;
    newtComponent form, b1, b2;
    newtInit();
    newtCls();

    newtOpenWindow(10, 5, 40, 6, "Button Sample");

    b1 = newtButton(10, 1, "Ok");
    b2 = newtCompactButton(22, 2, "Cancel");
    newtComponentAddCallback(b1, b1Callback, data);
    form = newtForm(NULL, NULL, 0);
    newtFormAddComponents(form, b1, b2, NULL);

    newtRunForm(form);

    newtFormDestroy(form);
    newtFinished();
}
```

Comment: I edit my answer. Don't forget to check as answered at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was:

- Set up a variable as `newtComponent answer`
- After destroy the form call this function `answer = newtFormGetCurrent(form);`
- and check if answer was my b1 button  `if( answer == b1 )`.

Comment: Just tried it out and this works like I want it to do :) ... And can easily add more buttons. Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to see a guide that explain about callback

```
typedef void (*newtCallback)(newtComponent, void *);

void newtComponentAddCallback(newtComponent co, newtCallback f, void * data);
void newtComponentTakesFocus(newtComponent co, int val);
```

Example of a callback

```
static void b1Callback(newtComponent co, void * data) 
{
// DO YOUR STUFF
}
```

Then add in your code:

```
newtComponentAddCallback(b1, b1Callback, NULL);
```

EDIT:

Change your callback in:  `*((int*)data) = 4;`

After the callback InitVal will be 4.

You have to study pointers before to contiune, I guess...

Comment: And newt does not use an event-driven architecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you by any chance have a link to some kind of guide on this? I have tried to add a callback function as you describe, but it does not seem to be called at all.

Comment: Point taken. Must have had a brain shutdown - not sure what I was thinking, but doesn't make much sense. Of course it should be like \*((int\*)data) = 4

Comment: Regardless of what I do, I cannot get it to work. If I select the "Ok" button and press Enter I'd expect the callback function to be called but that never happens. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Probably a problem with data. It is declared as void pointer, but is never asigned to an address. Then, first of all, try to add the callback without data: `newtComponentAddCallback(b1, b1Callback, NULL);`

Comment: Secondly try to declare data as int: `int data = 0` and change your code to `newtComponentAddCallback(b1, b1Callback, &data);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated function **newtRunForm()**. Use **newtFormRun()**. The second parameter in **newtFormRun()** is the struct with results, which returns everything you need to know what happened during form execution. Use it like this:

```
newtComponent form,b1,b2;
struct newtExitStruct exit_status;  
newtFormRun(form,&exit_status);                                                              
if (exit_status.reason==NEWT_EXIT_COMPONENT) {                                                                                                                                                     
    if (exit_status.u.co==b1) {  // ok button
        your code here
    }
    if (exit_status.u.co==b2) {  // cancel button
        your code here
    }
}
```

Check the *form.c* *newt.c* and *newt.h* source files for constants and more details.